# Low sound volume issues on Z97 motherboard and linux mint KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I've recently set up a new system with MSI Z97 gaming 5 motherboard however the first issue I've encountered was that the sound was crackling.
I've fixed that by updating the kernel to 3.16.3

Now the issue I have is that the sound is really silent on every output(audio jack, usb). Here are the things I've tried.

Checking Alsamixer: 
[image: Alsamixer]
Checking KDE audio/video settings and pulse.
[image: Pulse and kde settings #1]
[image: pulse and kde settings #]

Before trying to fix modprobe.h/alsa-base.conf by adding:

> options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0

to fix the crackling. (full alsa-base.conf here: http://paste.kde.org/p2mzluohd)

Am I missing something here? I have everything on 100% but it sounds like 20% on windows on every output (I've tried logitech speakers via generic audio jack, sony headphones via generic audio jack and logitech g930 headset via usb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So today I woke up turned on my system and everything works fine. Not sure what happened but I did reinstalls on pulseaudio before that and changed the snoop=0 to snoop=1 in the etc/modprobe.h/alsa-base.conf to the previous command I had there. So one of those things fixed it.

If someone comes up with the same issue be sure to install the latest stable kernel before you do any of the stuff I did.

EDIT: Also seems like sometimes the os thinks headphones are running instead of analog output thus resulting in lower sound volumes, you might want to look into that as well.